# Where can I specify the physical dimensions (width, height, depth) of a custom Android emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-hardware

I want to test my application on a particular Android device but the Android device is not in the list of emulators provided by Android Studio. I did set up a new device, however, I do not know from where to set the physical dimensions of the screen. I can only specify the screen size (e.g. 6.3 inches) and the resolution (e.g. 720 x 1560). How can I set the physical appearance e.g 160 x 74 x 7.7?